# Refresh keyboard without resigning and becoming first responder

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm wondering if there is possibility to refresh the keyboard, to be specifically, to be have the appearance of the dark or light keyboard without resigning and then first responder -

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

I have a button for brightness for the uitextfield to be dark/light. I tried to resign the textfield and then textfield become first responder. It doesn't look pretty.

I would like to get the keyboard to play along. Is it possible to make the keyboard stay up and animate from light to dark vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
textField.reloadInputViews()
```

Comment: I see it is working! I tried to put it in UIView.animate() but it seems it's not animating from light to dark. Is it possible do that too? Thank you!

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't you can do that :/